# Video background on a responsive two column layout with text in one column

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

So on a large screen I have this (using Bootstrap 5) which is fine:

[image]

But as soon as I shrink the screen the text in the first column spills out over the sections below as opposed to resizing correctly.

[image]

this was my initial code

```
<section class="bg-overlay ratio ratio-21x9  bg-soft-blue">
  <video poster="./assets/img/photos/movie2.jpg" src="./assets/media/home.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
  <div class="video-content">
  <div class="container">
       <div class="row  pt-10">
   <div class="col-lg-6 bg-soft-blue">
                         <h2 class="text-uppercase heading mb-5">Title</h2>
                         <p class="lead fs-lg lh-sm">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
                        </p>
                         <span><a href="#" class="text-uppercase btn btn-outline-primary rounded-pill" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal-signup">Read More</a></span>
                         </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
   </div>
   </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
    
  </div>
  <!-- /.video-content -->
</section>
```

I have tried playing with it like this:

```
<section>
 
       <div class="row pt-10" class="bg-soft-blue">
         
   <div class="col-lg-6 bg-soft-blue">
                         <h2 class="text-uppercase heading mb-5">Title</h2>
                         <p class="lead fs-lg lh-sm">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
                        </p>
                         <span><a href="#" class="text-uppercase btn btn-outline-primary rounded-pill" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal-signup">Button</a></span>
                         </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6 bg-overlay ratio ratio-4x3  ">
   <video poster="./assets/img/photos/movie2.jpg" src="./assets/media/home.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
       <div class="video-content">
  <div class="container">
  video here
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
    
  </div>
  <!-- /.video-content -->
</section>
    <!-- /section -->
```

But that actually makes it worse as it splits it into two sections. I tried an embed but then it doesn't auto play. I am ok if the video doesn't work on small screens and is just an image, but i need it to be responsive. I assume its a position issue in the first column, or maybe its just not doable. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your desired result is however, your problems seem to be caused by having the ratio classes on the column. Just fully nest the video container inside the column. Bootstrap grid elements (`.container`, `.row`, `.col-*`) work best when they *contain* BS components, not so well when you make *them* the component.

In this snippet the text will stack over the video on smaller screens and they will be side-by-side on medium and up, thanks to `.col-12.col-md-6`. Notice *all content elements* are *fully nested within* the `.col-*`s:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section>

  <div class="row pt-10 bg-soft-blue">

    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 bg-soft-blue">
      <h2 class="text-uppercase heading mb-5">Title</h2>
      <p class="lead fs-lg lh-sm">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
      <span><a href="#" class="text-uppercase btn btn-outline-primary rounded-pill" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal-signup">Button</a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">

      <div class="bg-overlay ratio ratio-4x3">
        <video poster="https://dummyimage.com/400x300/a00/cf.png&text=4:3" src="./assets/media/home.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
        <div class="video-content">
          <div class="container">
            video here
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</section>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

So i think this will work, posting in case it helps anyone else

```
<section class="bg-soft-blue">
<div class="row  pt-10">
<div class="col-lg-6">
<h2 class="text-uppercase heading mb-5">Title</h2>
<p class="lead fs-lg lh-sm">copy</p>
<span><a href="#" class="text-uppercase btn btn-outline-primary rounded-pill" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal-signup">Read More</a></span>
                     
</div>
 <div class="col-lg-6 ">
<div class="bg-overlay ratio ratio-21x9  ">
 <video poster="./assets/img/photos/movie2.jpg" src="./assets/media/home.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
<div class="video-content">
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
<!-- /.video-content -->
</section>
<!-- /section -->
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).